# how to print every subdirectory, but every subdirectory should be tabbed in before its printed

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

I'm trying to print every sub directory without using SearchOption.AllDirectories, only with Directory.GetDirectories for this i'm using recursion. my main problem is to print out every sub directory with two spaces in front like this :

```
1
  1,1
    1,1,1
2
  2,1
3
etc...

    class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string path = @"D:\Heaven Benchmark 4.0";
        WriteDirectories(path);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    static void WriteDirectories(string path)
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path/*, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories*/);
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(dirs[i] + "\n");
            if (Directory.GetDirectories(dirs[i]).Length > 0)
            {
                Console.Write("  "); WriteDirectories(dirs[i]);continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps keep track of the indent with another parameter to your method, and increment it when you do the recursive call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know C# so some of the syntax might be wrong, but you could do something like this

```
static void WriteDirectories(string path, int level)
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path/*, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories*/);
    for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
    {
        int l = level;
        while (l > 0) {
            Console.Write("  ");
            l -= 1;
        }
        Console.Write(dirs[i] + "\n");
        if (Directory.GetDirectories(dirs[i]).Length > 0)
        {
            WriteDirectories(dirs[i], level + 1);continue;
        }
    }
}
```

In your initial call just pass 0 for level. Or, if you don't want to expose this, make a private helper function that has this, and make the public facing function that accepts just a path call this with 0 for level.

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as. Just use a *level* parameter and call it as

```
WriteDirectories(path,0);
```

---

```
static void WriteDirectories(string path,int level)
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    foreach(var dir in dirs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(level*2, ' ') +  dir);
        WriteDirectories(dir, level + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, what I was talking about in my comment. Notice that we're using `Path.GetFileName` to get just the directory name (without the full path), so the output looks a little better with the indents:

```
static void WriteDirectories(string path, int indent = 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', indent * 2) + Path.GetFileName(path));

    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        WriteDirectories(subDir, indent + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear whether you wanted the full path for each directory or just that directory name, so given the layout, I've assumed just the name. Here it is...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteDirectories(@"D:\Heaven Benchmark 4.0");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void WriteDirectories(string path, int depth = 0)
    {
        string leafName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        string indent = new string(' ', depth * 2);
        Console.WriteLine($"{indent}{leafName}");

        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            WriteDirectories(directory, depth + 1);
        }
    }
```